# Differences between apostrophe-attachments and apostrophe-files?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

What are the main differences between the attachments and files modules, and are there specific use cases for each? Can permissions be applied to both? I'm very new to the platform, so trying to get up to speed on the hows and whys of how apostrophe accomplishes things.

Answer (score 2):

I am the architect of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

These modules are not alternatives, exactly. In fact, `apostrophe-files` and `apostrophe-images` are both built on top of `apostrophe-attachments`.

What is an `apostrophe-file`? It's a "piece" — an Apostrophe document with a title, some metadata, and in this case, an `attachment` field. Since it's a piece, just like any blog post or event, you can manage all of your files via the admin bar, you can use `apostrophe-files-widgets` to display download links around your site, and so on.

So what is an `attachment`? It's a schema field — a type of field you can include in the schema of any type of doc in Apostrophe, such as a piece or page.

Most schema field types are very simple. The `string` field type, for instance, consists of a string. The `boolean` field type is either true or false, and so on.

But attachments are a little tricky. In an ideal world... from a database design standpoint... the actual contents of the file would live right in your document; `doc.headshot` could be the actual JPEG data (or that, plus some metadata, perhaps).

But we can't do that, because files are very big, and even if they fit in a MongoDB doc (they don't always), it would be very, very inefficient especially when we're not interested in them right now.

So instead, here's what a typical `apostrophe-file` piece looks like in MongoDB if you use `findOne` to display it in the mongo shell. I've pared it down a little for simplicity. Notice the `attachment` property:

```
{
    "_id" : "xyz",
    "type" : "apostrophe-file",
    "title" : "Field Trip Permission Slip",
    "slug" : "file-field-trip-permission-slip",
    "attachment" : {
        "type" : "attachment",
        "_id" : "qqq",
        "name" : "permission-form",
        "extension" : "pdf"
    },
}
```

The `attachment` field has its own `_id`. And between that `_id`, the `name` property, and the `extension` property, the `apos.attachments.url()` method can put together a URL to download it.

So what does this buy us? Flexibility. Want to reuse a single library of PDFs all over your site? Use `apostrophe-files`, and use `apostrophe-files-widgets` to display download links around the site.

Want to attach a `resume` property to a specific person's `profile` piece and keep it *out* of the shared library? Use an `attachment` field in the schema for your piece type instead:

```
// in lib/modules/people
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  addFields: [
    {
      type: 'attachment',
      name: 'resume'
    }
  ]
}
```

We could have used a widget to pick a file, but we didn't want to clutter the shared library of files with thousands of resumes. So we just added an `attachment` property directly to resumes instead.

So in your templates, how do you get a URL for an attachment that is part of a piece? Like this:

`apos.attachments.url(data.piece.resume)`

See the documentation for more information about what you can do with `apostrophe-files`, `apostrophe-images` and `apostrophe-attachments`. There are plenty of examples in the tutorial, especially for `apostrophe-images-widgets`. Hopefully this answer gives you a sense of how and when to use `attachment` fields directly.

Hope this is helpful!